# Multiple enumeration of IEnumerable - StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, linq, deferred-execution

An interesting problem with IEnumerable and Linq.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var subject = "#Accountancy #premier #Agile #Apache #automation #Automation #banking #Banking #bankIngs #AutoMation";
    var hashtags = subject.Split('#').Select(hashtag => hashtag.Trim().ToUpper()).Distinct();

    var plurals = hashtags.Where((hashtag) =>
    {
        return hashtags.Contains($"{hashtag.ToUpper()}S");
    }).Select(h => $"{h.ToUpper()}S");      //.ToList(); (1) - will not break

    //filter hashtags
    hashtags = hashtags.Except(plurals);    //.ToList(); (2) - will not break

    //if iterate, would break with:
    //System.StackOverflowException was unhandled Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    foreach (var hashtag in hashtags)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(hashtag);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Curious on how would one explain why overflow exception occurs?

Comment: Use a new variable at the filter to avoid changing `hashtags` before fully iteration over it.

Comment: Read about **Linq and deferred execution** and combine this readings with the other two answers. Then you'll see why your code breaks. Deferred execution can lead to some pitfalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walk through it step by step.

1. Plurals is every word in *hashtags* which also has the same word ending in s
2. *Hashtags* is every word except plurals.

To execute 2, you must execute 1. However, *hashtags* is continually changing, so plurals is trying to execute not on the original collection, but on the result of 2 (which again, relies on the result of 1).

Your query will attempt to be:

```
hashtags = hashtags.Except(plurals);
```

Replacing `plurals`

```
hashtags = hashtags.Except(
            hashtags.Where(hashtag => { return hashtags.Contains($"{hashtag.ToUpper()}S"); })
                    .Select(h => $"{h.ToUpper()}S")
           );
```

But `hashtags` is `hashtags.Except(plurals);`

```
hashtags.Except(
            hashtags.Except(plurals).Where(hashtag => { return hashtags.Contains($"{hashtag.ToUpper()}S"); })
                    .Select(h => $"{h.ToUpper()}S")
           );
```

And then we need to replace `plurals` again.. and so on.

Your fixes (adding `.ToList()`) is the logical way to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You are re-assigning hashtags (which has not been evaluated) to another evaluation which is resulting in an infinite loop.  If you put the second evaluation in another variable, it will work:

```
var hashtags2 = hashtags.Except(plurals);

foreach (var hashtag in hashtags2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(hashtag);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the complete answer - `hashtags = hashtags.Except(hashtags.Where(h => h.StartsWith("B")));` doesn't throw a stack overflow exception.